# Add image to the bottom of a adjustable height section

Tags: html, css

I am trying to created a CSS design on my web app.  I am going for a banner that is flapping in the wind.  I want the banner to expand/scroll its height so all text will be displayed on the banner but regardless of how tall the banner is, I want to add a ripped section of the banner at the bottom of it.  The banner will be the same width in all cases.

Something like the example below (forgive the horrible Paint screenshot):

[image]

I can't seem to wrap my brain around how to accomplish this.  Any of you smart people have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think it'd be helpful if you could provide an example of what you have so far. For example, what's your HTML & CSS for the adjustable-height divs, just without the image at the bottom? Easier to add onto that.

I believe the best way would be to add an image element at the bottom of your adjustable element (assuming it's a `<div>`). Position it as absolute, and set it relative to the bottom of its parent container. You may have to fiddle with it a bit to get it to work. Don't forget to also set the position of the parent to relative.

If you'd like to see the shoddiest example ever, go here: https://jsfiddle.net/c2ptfv8o/

Good further reading on position: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Thank you for your example.  That is exactly what I needed to see in order to understand how to accomplish something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Give the container element "position:relative" (to create a new positioning context) and some bottom padding (to make space for the image). Then you can either use a background image set to be at the bottom of the container and not repeat vertically or absolutely position an image to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pseudo-elements for this. This way you don't require extra markup for each element.

```
.myDiv {
  position: relative;
}

.myDiv::after {
  content: url(image.jpg);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%; /* will be placed immediately where the div ends */
  width: 100%;
}
```

Based on the height of the 'banner curls', set a margin-bottom on .myDiv.

Or directly, without absolute, as long as you don't have paddings:

```
.myDiv::after {
  content: url(image.jpg);
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```